# GDB's .gdbinit issues annoying feedback when "focus cmd" is used

Tags: gdb

I am writting a `.gdbinit` file which would set up my layout as I always want it.So I put this inside the `.gdbinit`:

```
tui enable
tui new-layout mylayout {-horizontal {src 8 asm 2} 6 regs 4} 8 status 0 cmd 2
layout mylayout
refresh
set tui border-kind space
set tui tab-width 4
set tui compact-source on
focus cmd
```

Then I start GDB with a command `gdb-multiarch` and everything is set up correctly, except that I get this annoying feedback:

```
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

It looks like this:

[image]

I found out that if I comment out the last line in the `.gdbinit`, feedback message dissapears. But then `cmd` window is not focused.

How can I focus the `cmd` window and at the same time avoid the annoying feedback message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since GDB 9 you could use the `with` command.  Change the last line to:

```
with pagination off -- focus cmd
```

This will temporarily turn off pagination while the `focus` command runs, which will prevent the query being displayed.

Of course, that the query is displayed at all is clearly a bug... but the above should allow you to work around it.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I was looking for.